# Leetcode Valid Palindrome pass first test case but fail the second one when submit

Tags: python

I'm doing the valid palindrome problem at leetcode, below is the problem discription:

Given a string, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases.

Note: For the purpose of this problem, we define empty string as valid palindrome.

### Example 1:

**Input:**

```
A man, a plan, a canal: Panama
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

### Example 2:

**Input:**

```
race a car
```

**Output:**

```
false
```

Here is my code, my code was able to pass the first example `A man, a plan, a canal: Panama`, but failed the second one `race a car`. I have no idea why.

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        mystring = s.lower()
        mystring2 = ""
        for i in mystring:
            if i.isalnum():
                mystring2 += i
        return mystring2
    
        for i in range(0, int(len(mystring2)/2)):  
            if mystring2[i] != mystring2[len(mystring2)-i-1]: 
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: You seem to have a bunch of lines after `return mystring2` that are unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return `mystring2` after your first loop ends. You can directly start with the second loop. Your logic seems to be correct. Just doing this modification would work.

#### Correct Code -

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        mystring = s.lower()
        mystring2 = ""
        for i in mystring:
            if i.isalnum():
                mystring2 += i
    
        for i in range(0, int(len(mystring2)/2)):  
            if mystring2[i] != mystring2[len(mystring2)-i-1]: 
                return False
        return True
```

In your case, it is failing because you are just returning from the function halfway through your code. The last loop part of code was never getting executed in your case.

Also, in python, the last part of the loop can be written in a much simpler way -

#### Slightly Simplified code -

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        mystring = s.lower()
        mystring2 = ""
        for i in mystring:
            if i.isalnum():
                mystring2 += i

        return mystring2 == mystring2[::-1]
```

Similarly, you could also reduce the first part of your code as -

#### More Simplified Code -

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        mystring2 = ''.join([character.lower() for character in s if chracter.isalnum()])

        return mystring2 == mystring2[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to do this is to reverse the string and compare in more pythonic way

```
a = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
newA= [i.lower() for i in a if i.isalnum()]
print(newA == newA[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

At last, you have to return `true` or `false` only, not the string.

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s: str) -> bool:
        mystring = s.lower()
        mystring2 = ""
        for i in mystring:
            if i.isalnum():
                mystring2 += i

        return (mystring2 == mystring2[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though is not recommended, we can also solve this problem with a regular expression.

This'll pass:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, s):
        s = ''.join(re.findall(r'(?is)[a-z0-9]+', s)).lower()
        return s == s[::-1]
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        String original = s.replaceAll("(?i)[^a-z0-9]", "").toLowerCase();
        String reversed = new StringBuffer(original).reverse().toString();
        return original.equals(reversed);
    }
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var isPalindrome = function(s) {
    var original = s.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/isg, '');
    var reversed = original.split('').reverse().join('');
    
    return original.toLowerCase() == reversed.toLowerCase();
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.